# using a string to compare to multiple regex patterns

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

right now i am reading a file and storing a line into a string to compare to multiple regex patterns but it seems that it only detects the first pattern is there any way for it compare to both?
below is the code

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Project3 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException 
    {
        String i;
        String typenumber = "(\\s*)(int|double|float) (\\w) (=) (\\d)(;)";
        String function = "(\\s*)(void|int|string) (\\w) \\(\\) ";
        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(typenumber);
        Pattern t = Pattern.compile(function);
        String path = "input.txt";
        File file = new File(path);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        String string = scanner.nextLine();
        Matcher m = r.matcher(string);  
        Matcher n = t.matcher(string);


        while (scanner.hasNextLine())
        {
            if(m.find() )
            {
                if (string != null) 
            {
                    if (string.matches(typenumber)) 
                {
                    i = string;
                    System.out.println(i);
                    System.out.println(m.group(3) + " -> data type: " + m.group(2) + ";" + " scope: " + "value: "  + m.group(5));
                }
                    if (string.matches(function)) 
                {
                    i = string;
                    System.out.println(i);
                    System.out.println(m.group(3) + " -> data type: " + m.group(2) + ";" + " scope: ");
                }

            }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

this is also the input file i am using to test i am trying the regex to detect the void fun()

```
   int a = 1;

void fun() {

   char c;

   printf("%c", c);

 }

int main() {

int a = 3;

   fun();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your two patterns

**TYPE IDENTIFIER = NUMBER;**

**TYPE IDENTIFIER()**

can be integrated to one

**TYPE IDENTIFIER** ( **= NUMBER;** | **()** )

Try this.

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("(void|int|string)\\s+(\\w+)\\s*(=\\s*(\\d+)\\s*|\\(\\s*\\))");
File file = new File("input.txt");
try (Scanner in = new Scanner(file)) {
    while (in.hasNextLine()) {
        String i = in.nextLine();
        Matcher m = pat.matcher(i);
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(i);
            if (m.group(4) != null)
                System.out.println(m.group(2) + " -> data type: " + m.group(1) + ";" + " scope: " + "value: " + m.group(4));
            else
                System.out.println(m.group(2) + " -> data type: " + m.group(1) + ";" + " scope: ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you explain to me your pattern im a little lost on it

Comment: ah thank you, what if i wanted to detect the "}" symbol how would i go about putting that in the regex? cause i am trying to detect the } symbol to deterimine the scope of the variables